# How to make PHP run on other folders?

Tags: apache2, php

I have a PHP project in `/var/www/myproject`

I am wondering if I want to have my projects in `/home/myusername/Projects/myproject` and be able to run PHP on it, what should I do with Apache?

What if I want other folders to be also taken into account by Apache. So, for example:

```
/home/WorkProjects/myotherproject
```

and

```
/home/myusername/Projects/myproject
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In a terminal execute the following commands:

```
sudo chmod 775 home/myusername/Projects/myproject

sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

In the editor, change `DocumentRoot /var/www` to
`DocumentRoot /home/myusername/Projects/myproject`

Then you will see `<Directory "/var/www">`

Change your default `/var/www/` directory to `/home/myusername/Projects/myproject/`

Save and exit the editor.

Now restart your apache service:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

---

Also `chmod` your second directory.

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

Create alias  in `gedit`:

```
Alias /name /seconddirectory
<Directory /seconddirector>
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

[image]

**Now you can point to the directory http://127.0.0.1/your-name**

and by `127.0.0.1` to enter the root directory.

[image]

Comment: Hi nux. Thanks for this. What if I have several folders that I want apache to be aware of?

Comment: ok my friend happy to help you , but in response if the answer help you and true just mention that so it help other by knowing that is the correct answer , edit your question so i can answer so others will know or ask a new question

Comment: I have edited my question. Your answer would just work for a particular folder...

Comment: my answer is correct for the question you asked first , you should mention this from the first because it takes times to give a solution man

Comment: nux, look at the title. I was talking in plural. I just gave an example...

Comment: check the answer , gd luck

Answer (score 3):

You can use php built-in server instead of apache to run html/css and/or php files from a directory

```
cd /path/to/your/app
php -S localhost:8000
```

As output you'll get :

```
Listening on localhost:8000
Document root is /path/to/your/app
```