# .php file not execute outside /home/USER/public_html folder

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, php, phpmyadmin

would you have idea why my php script not working outside /home/USER-DIR/public_html folder.

Actual problem is i have installed phpmyadmin and i got the PHP code printed on screen, i follow and installed module `libapache2-mod-php` as i am using ubuntu 16.04 and webmin-virtualmin installed.

but the problem is not solved so i have try to check `phpinfo();` trying to placing file in `/var/www/html` folder, result are same no one .php file run outside my /home directory....

i have installed apache2, php7 (with `libapache2-mod-php` module).

[phpmyadmin error](https://paste.ubuntu.com/24932644/)

[phpinfo error](https://paste.ubuntu.com/24932710/)

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Hi, here is the link of pestbin `https://paste.ubuntu.com/24932644/`. Thanks

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: Did you check your apache conf files? Is PHP allowed to be executed for your directory?

Comment: @Ben can you please told me what i need to find exactly? i also have this doubt but not getting what exactly?

Comment: You can start by looking in **e.g** `/etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.conf` (not sure if the directory and filename is correct) and don't forget to `sudo apachectl restart` after changing the config.

Comment: And take a look here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/413808/how-to-make-php-run-on-other-folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Solved!

In ubuntu 16.04 you just need to decleare `AddType` into `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` and also in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf`.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```